# flashdevelop air for android error 102

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop

I used flashdevelop to create a default air for android project. But an apk cannot be generated.
The cmd windows when apk setup creation failed:

> Packaging: dist\Test.apk
>
> using certificate: cert\Test.p12...
>
> D:.......\application.xml: error 102: Invalid namespace
> http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.8
>
> APK setup creation FAILED.
>
> Troubleshooting:
>
> -did you build your project in FlashDevelop?
> -verify AIR SDK target version in application.xml

I have tested changing the version of "" in application.xml from 3.0 to 3.8, but it still refused to work.

I hope I can make it finally with your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have AIR 3.8 SDK installed?

In Flashdevelop, go to Help -> Check for updates. The latest version of Flashdevelop includes 3.8 as of this writing.

If you go to Project -> Properties and select AIR Mobile as Platform, you should be able to select 3.8 as version. If not, you don't have the latest version installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated the fd and apk was successfully generated.